# Unable to start the graphical user interface of RapidMiner in Mac OS

Tags: rapidminer

I was not able to start rapidminer by double clicking on lib/rapidminer.jar. I also tried java -jar lib/rapidminer.jar that also doesn't work.

I tried `./scripts/rapidminer` and rapid miner started

```
RAPIDMINER_HOME is not set. Trying the directory '.'...
No maximum Java memory defined, using 1024 Mb...
Java version: 16
grep: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory
Number of cores: 4
Number of GC Threads: 3
Starting RapidMiner from '.', using classes from './lib/rapidminer.jar'...
Java version: 16
Starting with CMS garbage collector
Starting in multi-core mode
RapidMiner version 5.3.008, Copyright (C) 2001-2012
RapidMiner comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions;
see license information in the file named LICENSE.
Usage: com.rapidminer.RapidMinerCommandLine [-f] PROCESS [-Mname=value]
  PROCESS       a repository location containing a process
  -f            interpret PROCESS as a file rather than a repository location (deprecated)
  -Mname=value  sets the macro 'name' with the value 'value'
```

I want to launch the GUI also
I tried : ./scripts/RapidMinerGUI

```
RAPIDMINER_HOME is not set. Trying the directory '.'...
grep: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory
Number of cores: 4
Number of GC Threads: 3
No maximum Java memory defined, using 1024 Mb...
Starting RapidMiner from '.', using classes from './lib/rapidminer.jar'...
Java version: 16
Starting with CMS garbage collector
Starting in multi-core mode
May 7, 2013 2:38:31 PM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: rapidminer.home is '.'.
May 7, 2013 2:38:31 PM com.rapid_i.Launcher main
INFO: Launching RapidMiner, platform ANY
May 7, 2013 2:38:32 PM com.rapidminer.tools.FileSystemService getUserRapidMinerDir
WARNING: Unable to create user home rapidminer directory /Users/.RapidMiner5
May 7, 2013 2:38:32 PM com.rapidminer.tools.ParameterService init
INFO: Reading configuration resource com/rapidminer/resources/rapidminerrc.
May 7, 2013 2:38:32 PM com.rapidminer.tools.FileSystemService getUserRapidMinerDir
WARNING: Unable to create user home rapidminer directory /Users/.RapidMiner5
May 7, 2013 2:38:32 PM com.rapidminer.tools.I18N <clinit>
```

Please help me run the rapidminer gui in Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked while i tried it as `Root` user.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `RAPIDMINER_HOME` variable with the location of RapidMiner folder:

```
export RAPIDMINER_HOME=/home/user/development/rapidminer-5
```